# how to use webbroswer authentication

Tags: .net, winforms, httprequest, digital-certificate

I have .net Application in which i have webbroswer control in which i do following steps

Navigate to site. (Using Code)
Popup to select installed digital signature.
Enter user id and password. (on website)
system login... (on website)

I want now my HttpWebRequest to navigate a URL which is only accceible after login to download particular PDF...

How can i do this....

because when i try to create new object it treat that request as not authenticated what i think
so there will be some mechanism so i can pass all cookie session values to that reuquest object or any way to access that URL with webbroswer function ... without disturbing UI of webbroswer.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `CookieContainer` property and class.

Comment: is cookie container will also give me session states?

Comment: problem is that its ok i pass cookie but that site also need digital certifcate...

Comment: request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer ();

request.CookieContainer.SetCookies (myUri, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);